# What Causes this NullReferenceException when Accessing a Cell of a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` control and I'm checking if I'm getting the correct value of `column 0`

[image]

But when I click my button to echo the value, I always get this error...

[image]

Are there errors in my code? Or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a new project a and I it worked... strange.

Answer (score 1):

Break up your long/compound statement into several lines/statements:

- Is dbView1 null?
- Is dbView1.CurrentRow null?
- Is dbView1.CurrentRow.Index equal to -1, or greater than the number of rows?
- Is dbView1[dbView1.CurrentRow.Index] null?

Answer (score 1):

When the datagridview initially bind with data, and you didn't click any row or any cell or the datagridview, the CurrentRow.Index property won't set to the "visibly" selected row.
But when you run through each row, you will find that dgView.Rows[?].Selected has set to either true or false. you can create a method with try catch to catch the exception when getting the property of CurrentRow.Index. Try the following code.

```
try
{
    MessageBox.Show(dgView1[0,dgView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value.ToString());
}
catch
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dgView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (dgView1.Rows[i].Selected) 
        {
           MessageBox.Show(dgView1[0,dgView1.Rows[i].Index].Value.ToString());
           return;
        }     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most possible reason is that when you click the button, the form is focus on the 2nd row (row with *), this row has no reference to it until you click & input something in a cell of the row (if so, another row with * will be generated automatically). If you don't want the row to be generated automatically, just set `dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows` to false.

Comment: I just checked it, but it seems that it gets the current row index of the gridview

Comment: @yonan Here I perfectly reproduced your error. Make your gridview two rows, one with value and one is marked as *. If you are selecting row 1, the error will not occur. If you are selecting row *, it will throw the exception, just like what happened in your question.

Comment: ah... thanks... but it's already working now. You play DOTA right..? hehe.

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing

`dgView.CurrentRow.Index` with `dgView.SelectedRows[0].Index`

and set the property `Multiselect` to `False`, `SelectionMode` = `FullRowSelect`

Did that help? :)

Comment: Also, when that exception is thrown and the debugging is paused, check each value to see which one is NULL and post it here :)

Comment: i tried tracing the values of the current selected row and column. It seems correct. But still I can't get the value i supplied in that particular cell.

Comment: Can you check which object is NULL and let us know?

Comment: If the Row and Columns is fine, the only thing left to be NULL i think is `Value`. Is it NULL?

Comment: this code dataGridView1[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Value returns null

Comment: Yes yonan, but a NullReferenceException is thrown as one of the objects specified in that line is NULL. So when you hover over the objects when the exception is thrown, which object is Null?

Comment: Hmm, interesting... When value is NULL, what are the values for the Column and Row? Column should be 0, but what is the value for Row?

Comment: 0, but if you select the second row the value of row is 1. just like as expected.

Comment: but i still don't know why I can't fetch the value I entered on that particular cell

Comment: What is the DataSource for the DataGridView? I am just asking, as according to the image you have pasted, the 2nd row is empty (Index 1). But you are 100% sure that the 2nd row of the 1st column is NOT empty, is it? Try replacing the indexes with fixed values (0,0) and check whether it is working :)

Comment: I tried this:  MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1[0, 0].Value.ToString());

Comment: the dataGrid has no datasource. but its column is editable so i can add values on it